# How to get the MimeType of a file with special character in android

Tags: android

I am trying to get the mime type of the file in android and I'm able to get the mime type using this code

```
val extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(file)
        val fileType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension.toLowerCase())
```

But the issue is if the file name contains space or other special character

e.g  `/storage/emulated/0/Download/Snow Falling Down.mp4`
 it returns null.

Comment: what deos `getFileExtensionFromUrl` return?

Comment: it returns the file extension like .mp4. but doesn't return anything if the file name contains a special character or space

Comment: and cannot you get your file extension by yourself?

Comment: I'm trying to know if a file is an image or a video but if I use extension for that then I have to consider all the  possible file extensions which I think is not a good way

Comment: cannot you get file extension by yourself? i mean `mp4`

Comment: and if it is still too hard use `Uri.encode()` static method to get a valid, %'-escaped url

Comment: I can use either the getFileExtensionFromUrl or the lastIndexof(.) to get the file extension

Comment: as i said: either get the extension by yourself or use `Uri.encode()` static method  to get a valid, %'-escaped url - however i would use `Uri.encode()`

Comment: ok, let's say I have two files with extension .jpg and .png now I want to know if it's an image file or not without having to check the extensions individually...how do I do that?

Comment: you can only use `getMimeTypeFromExtension` - there is no other method

Comment: Ok, thank you for your response

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this method to get File extension. Then you can get MimeType from extension

**In Java**

```
public static String getExtension(String fileName) {
    String encoded;
    try {
        encoded = URLEncoder.encode(fileName, "UTF-8").replace("+", "%20");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        encoded = fileName;
    }

    return MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(encoded).toLowerCase();
}
```

In Kotlin

```
fun getExtension(fileName: String): String {
    val encoded: String = try {
        URLEncoder.encode(fileName, "UTF-8").replace("+", "%20")
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        fileName
    }

    return MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(encoded).toLowerCase()
}
```

**or as Kotlin extension:**

```
fun File.getExtension(): String {
    val encoded: String = try {
        URLEncoder.encode(name, "UTF-8").replace("+", "%20")
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        name
    }

    return MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(encoded).toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())
}
```

Comment: yeah, I used Uri.encode().Thank you for your response

Answer (score -1):

Can you try with :

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(paths);
File file = new File(uri.getPath());
val extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(file)
```

Comment: This returns `null` in case file name contains a space.